# Multiple Timeseries graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, time-series

I am trying to create a time series plot that has multiple data over the years. I would like to just plot the years and get the data to run from start date to end date. Here I have converted the respective columns to dates and then combined them but I do not get the result I am looking for.

The data is available from this  website: https://www.businessinsider.co.za/coronavirus-deaths-how-pandemic-compares-to-other-deadly-outbreaks-2020-4?r=US&IR=T

Something like this where the data doesn't start in the same year or end in the same year:
https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/410/cpsprodpb/6E25/production/_111779182_optimised-mortality-nc.png

(time period vs deaths caused)

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
otherDiseaseData <- structure(list(ï..Disease = structure(c(11L, 2L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 
                                                            1L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 10L), .Label = c("Asian Flu", "blackdeath", 
                                                                                                          "Cholera", "Covid 19", "Ebola", "HIV", "Hong Kong Flu", "Mers", 
                                                                                                          "Russian Flu", "Sars", "smallpox", "spanish flu", "Swine Flu"
                                                            ), class = "factor"), Start = c(0L, 1347L, 1918L, 1981L, 1899L, 
                                                                                            1957L, 1889L, 1968L, 2009L, 2019L, 2014L, 2012L, 2002L), End = c(1979L, 
                                                                                                                                                             1351L, 1919L, 2020L, 1923L, 1958L, 1890L, 1970L, 2010L, 2020L, 
                                                                                                                                                             2016L, 2020L, 2003L), Death = c(300000L, 225000000L, 50000L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             2360000L, 1500000L, 1100000L, 1000000L, 1000000L, 151700L, 101526L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             11300L, 866L, 774L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       -13L))


yrs <- otherDiseaseData$Start
    yr <- as.Date(as.character(yrs), format = "%Y")
    yStart <- year(yr)

    yrs <- otherDiseaseData$End
    yr <- as.Date(as.character(yrs), format = "%Y")
    yStart <- year(yr)

    otherDiseaseData$x <- paste(otherDiseaseData$Start,otherDiseaseData$End)
    otherDiseaseData
    ggplot(otherDiseaseData, aes(y = Death, x = otherDiseaseData$x),xlim=0000-2000) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've fully understood what you're asking for, but my interpretation is this:

```
df <- reshape::melt(otherDiseaseData, measure.vars = c("Start", "End"))

ggplot(df %>% filter(Disease != "smallpox", Death != 225000000)) + 
  geom_line(aes(value,Death, colour = Disease), size = 2) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = filter(df, Disease != "smallpox", Death != 225000000, variable != "Start"),
                                          aes(label = Disease, x = value, y = Death)) + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", aspect.ratio = 1) + 
  ylab("Number of Deaths") + xlab("Year")
```

I've used the *reshape* package to reorganise the given data, and then *ggrepel* to label the bars. I've had to remove some data as it really throws the scale, which I've ended up making logarithmic to spread the data out a little. It gives you this plot:

[image]

It's not perfect but it might be heading in the right direction? Apologies if I've misunderstood what you were angling for.

Comment: Thank you! It was what I was trying to produce! Perfect thank you

Comment: How would I add a title to this graph please?

Comment: If "p" is your plot, the code would look like:     p + labs(title = "My Title", subtitle = "My Subtitle"